# The method 'collection' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: collection("user")

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aDSI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLR7H.png)

I don't know why I have this error.
The method 'collection' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: collection("user")

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Aside from that, none of the code in the pictures you shared calls `collection` making it hard to say where the problem is. I highly recommend taking a few moments to study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Following the guidance in there will give you the best chance that someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  getProfileDetailFromFirestore(String token) {
    firebaseFirestore.collection("user").doc(token).snapshots().listen((value) {
      profileDataSink.add(profileObject.fromMapObject(value.data()));
    });
  }

  Future<void> followOrUnFollowUser(String selfToken, String friendToken,
      ProfileObject self, ProfileObject friend, bool isUserFollowing) async {
    await firebaseFirestore.collection("user").doc(selfToken).update({
      "following": isUserFollowing
          ? FieldValue.arrayRemove([friend.toMapLimitedData()])
          : FieldValue.arrayUnion([friend.toMapLimitedData()]),
    });
    await firebaseFirestore.collection("user").doc(friendToken).update({
      "follower": isUserFollowing
          ? FieldValue.arrayRemove([self.toMapLimitedData()])
          : FieldValue.arrayUnion([self.toMapLimitedData()]),
    });
  }

  dispose() {
    _postCreatedController.close();
    _profileObjectController.close();
  }
}
```

Here is a my code, I am getting the error in the title whenever I try to click on a button my app to see my unique profile.